# cant input today date with sql

Tags: sql

```
$sql=$Db1->query("INSERT INTO TABLENAME SET username='$username', log='Log text here ', date='".date()."'");
```

The problem is below

username and logs are inserted correctly but date is not saved , it saves 0000-00-00 etc
Thanks to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the date column type in your table as "TIMESTAMP" and change the code to this

```
$sql=$Db1->query("INSERT INTO TABLENAME SET username='$username', log='Log text here ', date=NULL");
```